# Using apply functions instead of for loops in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to replace a for loop in my code with an apply function, and i attempted to do it in all the possible ways, using sapply and lapply and apply and mapply, always seems to not work out, the original function looks like this

```r
ds1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 2), col2 = c("A", "B"))
ds2 <- data.frame(colA = c("A", "B"), colB = c(90, 110))

for(i in 1:nrow(ds1)){
  if(is.na(ds1$col1[i])){
    ds1$col1[i] <- ds2[ds2[,"colA"] == ds1$col2[i], "colB"]
  }
}
```

My latest attempt with the apply family looks like this

```r
ds1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(NA, 2), col2 = c("A", "B"))
ds2 <- data.frame(colA = c("A", "B"), colB = c(90, 110))

sFunc <- function(x, y, z){
  if(is.na(x)){
    return(z[z[,"colA"] == y, "colB"])
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

ds1$col1 <- sapply(ds1$col1, sFunc, ds1$col2, ds2)
```

Which returns `ds2$colB` for each row, can someone explain to me what I got wrong about this?

Comment: ok will create an example dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sapply` only iterates over the first vector you pass. The other arguments you pass will be treated as whole vectors in each loop. To iterate over **m**ultiple vectors you need **m**ultivariate apply, which is **m**apply.

```
sFunc <- function(x, y){
  if(is.na(x)){
    return(ds2[ds2[,"colA"] == y, "colB"])
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

mapply(sFunc, ds1$col1, ds1$col2)
#> [1] 90  2
```

Comment: I get an `Error in `[.default`(z, , "colA") : incorrect number of dimensions` error

Comment: @JimmyBower sorry - that's because it's trying to iterate over columns instead of rows of ds2. Now updated

Comment: oh so I can't supply the apply functions with dataframes?

Comment: You can, but you need to be careful. remember a dataframe is actually a list of vectors, so iterating over it normally means iterating over columns, not rows. In `apply` you can get it to iterate over rows by setting MARGIN as 1, but not with mapply

Comment: if it is not too much to ask, is it possible you show me how i can do this with supplying the data frame rather than calling it from outside the function?

Comment: Usually I would do this by using an anonymous function from inside the mapply itself. You can't really pass a whole data frame as a parameter directly to the `mapply` because with an apply statement you are saying: iterate over the following object, and for each element do the following...

Answer (score 2):

A join would be useful here. You can do it in base R :

```
transform(merge(ds1, ds2, by.x = "col2", by.y = "colA"), 
          col1 = ifelse(is.na(col1), colB, col1))[names(ds1)]

#  col1 col2
#1   90    A
#2    2    B
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(ds1, ds2, by = c("col2" = "colA")) %>%
    mutate(col1 = coalesce(col1, colB)) %>%
    select(names(ds1))
```